# How to reinstall broken packages of python

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint, python-3.6

```
dpkg: error processing package python-cairo (--configure):

package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

There is a broken package in the python. Whenever i try installing a package, it throws this error.

Please help me to solve this out ! Thanks !

Comment: After you fix it, please make sure never to install system-wide packages with `pip`. It will step on the feet of the Python packages installed with the package manager. If you absolutely need an external Python package that's not available in your repository, use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), so you can make those installations per project.

Comment: sure, Can you suggest some other way to erase these files and reinstall ?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python-cairo
sudo apt-get install python-cairo
```

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of python-cairo:
 python-gtk2 depends on python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1).

Comment: Couldn't remove because of dependency problem

Comment: @Sri try adding `--force-depends` to the options to `dpkg` already given above. (And be really cautious with this option. You can cause real havoc, if you use it indiscriminately.)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. It works

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <packagename>
sudo apt-get remove <packagename>
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-cairo
 python-gtk2
 gimp
 python-apt
 python-attr
 python-beautifulsoup
 python-blinker
 python-notify
 python-webkit
 python-aptdaemon
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) It's throwing a list of files, now